# CKEDITOR working locally but not in server in Internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor v4.11.4 which is working fine locally. But after uploading it to the demo server(IIS) CKEditor is not showing in internet explorer. All plugin files are already up to date in server.
[image]

Image from Local machine

Image from server.
[image]

Comment: As said here https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_installation.html "CKEditor comes with a sample that you can check to verify if the installation was successful as well as a few “next steps” ideas and references to further resources.

Open the following page in the browser to see the sample:"
`http://<your site="">/ckeditor/samples/index.html`

Does CKEditor show in that page? Are there any JS errors? Is it working with another browser?

Comment: Yes it is showing

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor plugins are usually many 3rd party dependencies. In that case please use defer in the script tag. Hope it may work

Comment: let me try this